# How to find the dimension of the Vector Space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Find the dimension of a vector space $\mathbb K$ over a field $\mathbb F$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb K$ ($\mathbb F$) where |$\mathbb K$|=$43^8$ and |$\mathbb F$|= $43^2$.

My Attempt: I had found this result...

Let V be a vector space having dimension n whenever |$\mathbb F$|= $p^k$, where p is a prime and  k$\in$ $\mathbb N$ then |V($\mathbb F$)| = $|\mathbb F|^n$ = $p^{kn}$. Using this is not giving me the right conclusion! Any help?

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but what is $\mathbb K$ here? It doesn't seem entirely clear to me

Comment: @StephenDonovan It's a vector space over the field $\mathbb F$.

Comment: "Using this is not giving me the right conclusion!" What conclusion do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $43^8=\left(43^2\right)^4$, $\dim\mathbb{K}=4$. This is a direct application of the formula that you have mentioned.